# How to simulate an event with jQuery?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I am working with a third party plugin, that has a small bug. This bug happens when the control renders, and when I doubleclick on a header row inside the table it fixes my problem through this trigger inside the plugin:

```
$(".grid tr").live("dblclick",function() {
    //code here 
});
```

So, what I need is, knowing the exact `<tr>`, I want to simulate that double click, so I can fix the bug on the control onload callback.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".grid tr").trigger("dblclick");
```

This will trigger the double click event.

If there is indeed a bug with the plugin, you should create a bug report with them so hopefully they can (a) tell you are doing it wrong, here is how to do it right or (b) fix it in a future release.

Comment: You can also use the direct bind function name shorthand without a parameter. eg. `$('.grid tr').dblclick();`

Comment: Yes, it is - just adding to your answer for completeness, rather than making my own - seemed unnecessary as your's was fine.

Comment: i know, i am trying to contact the developer. thanx

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".grid tr").trigger('dblclick');
```